# Will NEWSEQUENTIALID() SQL always generate unique ID irrespective of Host computer?

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is a generic query, My scenario is: I have a DB(MS SQL) and create a table with a column as uniqueidentifier and assign the values using NEWSEQUENTIALID(), I know it will be unique id always. But what if I am deploying the same DB on three machine (2 machines are transactional DBs and the third is replication DB). In the replication DB, I will update the column to not assign value by itself. From the two transactional DBs, I will replicate the data to the replication DB daily. NOW THE QUERY IS, will the ids generated on the two transactional DB be unique when I replicate to the replication DB. ie. is the IDs generated unique across any machine? or is that only one machine?

Comment: Has my answer below successfully  answered your question, or is there anything else you are unclear about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will still be globally unique.

Have a look as the MSDN page for it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189786.aspx

By "Specified Computer" it is refering to the fact that the GUID will be greater than those previously generated. So being greater than the last generated is only guaranteed for that machine. It's uniqueness is Global.

Comment: Only guaranteed on machines with a network card (which I guess must be 99.9999% of SQL Servers)

Comment: This is true. Also if he's replicating data between machines I assume they have Network cards.

Comment: @Tom.Bowen89: I had already gone through the link and a bit confused as it says "Creates a GUID that is greater than any GUID previously generated by this function on a specified computer since Windows was started", Please check the word SPECIFIED COMPUTER, that means I guess on one computer.... My scenario is that two machines (trancation DBs) will be on client site, while the Replication DB will be inhouse to me, where the repliction is not actual DB-DB repliction but a concept implemented using windows service and calls done via webservice.

Comment: By "Specified Computer" it is refering to the fact that the GUID will be greater than those previously generated. So being greater than the last generated is only guaranteed for that machine. It's uniqueness is Global.